# Angular2 webpack configuration url is not proper

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular2-webpack-starter beta version for that project was working.
I have also included primeng in the project as well.
But after I have updated my npm, node, webpack-dev-server, Now i am getting
**{% if (webpackConfig.metadata.ENV === 'development') { %} {% } %}**
in the browser screen.
Also url is also having extra content like.
http://localhost:3000/**%3C%=%20webpackConfig.metadata.baseUrl%20%%3E#**/home

Answer (score 0):

I get exactly the same problem when starting the server from a VS code terminal.

Starting from normal windows command prompt or cmder works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checking?
**{ test: /.html$/,  loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: [ root('src/index.html') ] }**
in webpack.config.js